# How to perform backup to local disk with Windows Server Backup on SBS 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, windows-sbs-2008

How to perform backup to local disk with Windows Server Backup on SBS 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2008 provides the backup technology for Windows Small Business Server 2008. Windows Server Backup [Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770266%28WS.10%29.aspx) for Windows Server 2008. Backing Up Your Server [manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753528.aspx).